# I got problem with my 1st function in menu

Tags: c

Do you have any idea how I can fix the function of menu selection #1?

I'm struggling only with the 1st menu selection, everything else is working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXN 100

int menu(){
    printf("WELCOME TO C-PROGRAM WORKING WITH NUMBERS\n");
    printf("> 1- Input numbers (until 0 is given)\n");
    printf("> 2- Print numbers in orginal order\n");
    printf("> 3- Search a given number\n");
    printf("> 4- Calculate the total between two given numbers\n");
    printf("> 5- Print numbers in ascending order\n");
    printf("> 6- Quit\n");
    printf("Select: ");
    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    return choice;
}

int isFul (int*a, int n){   
    return n==MAXN;
}
int isEmpty (int*a, int n){   
    return n==0;
}
int inputNumberArray (int a[])
{
    int x;
    int n=0;
    do{
        scanf("%d",&x);
        a[n]=x;
        n=n+1;
    }
    while (a!=0);
    n=n-1;
    return n;
}
int search(int x, int *a, int n){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) if (a[i]==x) return i;
    return -1;
}
void printarray(int*a, int n){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) printf("Result: %d\n", a[i]);
}
void printAsc(int*a, int n){ 
    int** adds =(int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) adds[i]= &a[i];
    int* t;
    for (i=0;i<n-1; i++)
       for(j=n-1; j>i; j--)
         if (*adds[j]< *adds[j-i]){
            t=adds[j];
            adds[j]=adds[j-1];
            adds[j-1]=t;
         }
    for (i=0;i<n; i++) printf("Result: %d \n", *adds[i]);
    free(adds);  
}
int sumArray (int a[],int n)
{
    int i=0,s=0;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        s=s+a[i];
    }
    return s;
}
int main(){ 
    int a[MAXN];
    int n=0;
    char c;
    int value;
    int choice;
    do
    {
    do
    {   choice= menu();
        switch(choice){
            case 1:{
                if (isFul(a,n)) printf("\n Sorry! The numbers is full.\n");
                else{  
                   n=inputNumberArray(a);
                   printf("Added!\n");
                   }
                   break;
            }
            case 3:{
                if (isEmpty(a,n)) printf("\n Sorry! No number found!.\n");
               else {
                   printf ("Input the searched value:");
                   scanf("%d", &value);
                   int pos = search(value, a, n);
                   if (pos<0) printf("Not found!\n");
                   else printf("Postion is found: %d\n", pos);
               }   break;
            }
            case 2:{
                if (isEmpty(a,n)) printf("\n Sorry! No number found!.\n");
                else
                   {
                     printarray(a,n);
                   } break;
                   }
            case 4:{
                if (isEmpty(a,n)) printf("\n Sorry! No number found!.\n");
                printf("Result: %d",sumArray(a,n));

                break;
            }
            case 5:{
                if (isEmpty(a,n)) printf("\n Sorry! No number found!.\n");
                else
                   {
                    printAsc(a,n);          
                   } break;
                   } 
              default: printf ("Goodbye!");
              break;
            }
            } while (choice>0 && choice<6);
            printf("Try again?(Y/N)"); scanf("%c",&c);
        } while (c=='Y'||c=='y');
if (c=='N'||c=='n') printf("Program ended!");
             getchar();
             return 0;
}
```

My code looks like above. I tried many time but function #1 doesn't seem to work, it just makes the whole code freeze. When the application starts, I press 1 and  it keeps standing there, nothing happens. Is there any way to fix this or any way to replace the #1 in the menu charts?

Comment: What is `func#1`?

Comment: You have an infinite loop because of: `do {...} while (a!=0);`. This will always be true, since `a` is the address of the array.

Comment: It should be `while (x != 0)`

Comment: @anonmess `inputNumberArray()` is called from menu item 1.

Comment: okay i will fix that

Comment: @anonmess its the 1st thing in the menus

Comment: You should print a prompt when asking for the numbers, so you can see that it isn't frozen.

Comment: @barmar got that sir xd

Comment: In `inputNumberArray()` do you mean `do { ... } while (a[n]!=0);`? (while (a!=0); checks if the array address is not 0 which creates an endless loop except if you pass a NULL pointer to the function. BTW: Passing an array to a function without passing its size can lead to out-of-bounds access.

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger. Or add output (`printf(...)`) for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an endless loop in function `inputNumberArray()`

```
int inputNumberArray (int a[])
{
    int x;
    int n=0;
    do{
        scanf("%d",&x);
        a[n]=x;
        n=n+1;
    }
    while (a!=0); /* This checks if the pointer (array address) a is not a NULL pointer */
    n=n-1;
    return n;
}
```

Change the loop condition to

```
    do{
        /* ... */
    }
    while (a[n]!=0); /* This checks if the previously entered number is not 0 */
```

Note that this function will return `-1` if you enter 0 as the first number.

BTW: As you use C, not C++, you should write functions without arguments as `returntype function(void)` instead of `returntype function()`.